# Что за тип у переменной?

Tags: c

Есть переменная a

```
struct {
    short kto;
    int prichital;
    char tot;
} (*(*(*a)))()()();
```

Какой размер у переменной и как его расшифровать?

Comment: А не указатель ли это на функцию?

Comment: Поясните, что вы подрузомеваете под расшифровкой размера?

Comment: указатель на указатель на указатель на функцию

Comment: Если вам нужен её размер - пользуйтесь ф-цией sizeof. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: >>пользуйтесь ф-цией sizeof<< зачем ему знать размер указателя? Автор не пояснил размер чего он хочет узнать... + Неизвестен компилятор, мой mingw вообще не хотит такой код компилировать.

Comment: А вообще честно говоря бред какой-то, даже не компилируется.

Comment: @test123 sizeof позволяет измерять любой размер, т.к. никто не запрещает писать `sizeof(***a)` очевидно что любое измерение - будет указатель.

Comment: @nick_n_a, sizeof(***a), ну, допустим, это будет размер структурки, а что за размер нужен автору? Я бы тогда предложил размер структуры + 3 размера указателя, так более правдоподобно звучит...

Comment: @test123 есть функция sizeof - пусть автор в неё подставляет то что он хочет измерять - и она померяет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [правилу часовой стрелки](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), а так же сайту [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%20%28*%28*%28*a%29%29%29%28%29%28%29%28%29%3B), переменная `a` является:

> указателем на указатель на указатель на функцию, возвращающую функцию, возвращающую функцию, возвращающую упомянутую безымянную структуру.

Т.к. в Си запрещено возвращать из функции функцию (а не указатель на неё), то данный код [не является валидным](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nyHvJ2MqHCWpE1us).

> error: 'a' declared as function returning a function

Чтобы он стал валидным, нужно возвращать указатель на функцию, [получится так](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XJMeDcK9ODZUP80l):

```
struct {
   ...
} (*(*(*a)())())();
```

При этом безымянность структуры накладывает свои ограничения. Указатель объявили, но инициализировать чем-то полезным, чтобы иметь возможность вызвать - проблематично.

Говорить же о размере некоторой сущности, не являющейся валидной с точки зрения языка нельзя вовсе. Ну а после приведения к компилируемому виду можно [воспользоваться `sizeof`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IlpQY07l8Kaj80hE).